# Ionic2 app.bundle.js file disappear

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm beggining with Ionic2, I made the quick tutorial with these lines :

```
$ ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2
$ cd MyIonic2Project/
$ ionic serve
```

It perfectly works, but after I decide to add new folder with new .ts files in app/pages/ and modify previous folder name in this folder, the app.bundle.js in www/build/js suddenly faded away so now I have a blank page.

Does someone have an explanation and knows how to make it reappear (by building app.ts I guess) ?

Just to precise, I made all the update npm cordova and ionic@beta.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: let me know if it helps - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-fails-with-app-bundle-js-not-found-for-typescript-app/45266/6

Comment: I already have the last update of ionic@beta and ionic-framework is already replace by ionic-angular too

Comment: But in the link it was mentioned that some of the latest beta dint worked and installing some particular beta version helped

Comment: I have the same problem, any help? :(

Comment: I just have a compilation error so the app.ts won't be build to app.bundle.js. Now it works fine for me, did you make all the update ?

Answer (score 1):

When creating new pages for Ionic 2, I recommend creating pages via the CLI generator because it'll create all the necessary files correctly. Here's an example of the command line you would enter in the terminal at the root directory of your project. 
`ionic g page myNewPage` (where `myNewPage` is the name of your new page)
Please note when you name pages use the `PascalCasing` naming convention. The generator will then create a new child folder containing the new .js/.ts, .scss and .html page using `kebob-casing` naming convention. Also, add the new `.scss` file to the `./app/theme/app.core.scss` file, a reminder will be noted in the terminal after the new pages are generated.

For more details about the CLI page generator, see the [API Doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/generate/)